# Is the enthalpy change of a reversible adiabatic expansion any different from enthalpy change of a irreversible adiabatic expansion?

Tags: thermodynamics

Some sites say that adiabatic expansions of ideal gases in general have $\triangle H =0$ , whereas some say it is not.

I tried to find $\triangle H$ by considering a reversible adiabatic process where Initial conditions are $P_1, V_1$ and $T_1$ and final variables are $P_2, T_2, V_2$ also it implies $PV^\gamma = k$, hence $\triangle U = \frac{P_2V_2 - P_1V_1}{\gamma-1}$, $\triangle (PV) =P_2V_2 - P_1V_1$ and since $\triangle H$ = $\triangle U$ + $\triangle (PV)$ , $\triangle H =\frac{\gamma (P_2V_2 - P_1V_1)}{\gamma -1}$

What is wrong with this proof?

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice. Make *edits* to the first instead. Please [visit the help center for more information](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: "Some sites say ..." Really? Which ones? Please provide references in support of such statements.

Comment: $\Delta H = 0$ statement for adiabatic expansion  ($Q=0$) of an ideal gas would be true for expansion against vacuum in [Joule-Thomson effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect) scenario ($W=0$), as  $\Delta T = 0$,  $\Delta U = 0$ and $\Delta (PV) = 0$

Comment: Are we talking about a closed system or can we also include an adiabatic flow through an open system?

Comment: For a closed system, do you think it is possible to have an adiabatic reversible process between the same initial and final states as an adiabatic irreversible process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the enthalpy change of a reversible adiabatic expansion any different from enthalpy change of a irreversible adiabatic expansion?

Enthalpy is a **state function**, and its changes $\Delta H$ are independent of the path from state $1$ to state $2$. Thus, an adiabatic reversible process or adiabatic irreversible process, will yield an identical $\Delta H$.

> So some sites say that adiabatic expansions of ideal gases in general have $△H=0$ , whereas some say it is not.

The enthalpy change for an ideal gas only depends on temperature. The only way that this change is zero is proved below
\begin{align}
  \Delta H = \int_{T_1}^{T_2} c_p^\pu{ig}(T) \; dT = 0 \therefore
   \boxed{\Delta H = 0 \Leftrightarrow T_1 =T_2} \tag{1}
\end{align}

In consequence, ideal gases suffer an isenthalpic process if and only if the process is isothermal. Adiabatic reversible or irreversible processes have a change in temperature, and thus, cannot be isenthalpic.

> What is wrong with this proof?

The proof is fine. Remember it is only valid for:

1. An ideal gas.
2. It has constant-pressure and constant-volume heat capacities, so that $\gamma$ is also constant.

However, if you pay attention, there was no need to invoke any reversible/irreversible adiabatic process. It is a general expression, I will show you another way
\begin{align}
  \Delta U &= \int_{T_1}^{T_2} c_V^\pu{ig} \; dT \\
  \Delta U &= c_V^\pu{ig} \int_{T_1}^{T_2} \; dT \\
  \Delta U &= c_V^\pu{ig} (T_2 - T_1) \\
  \Delta U &= \frac{c_V^\pu{ig}}{R} (RT_2 - RT_1) \hspace{1 cm} (\text{use that $R = c_P^\pu{ig} - c_V^\pu{ig}$})  \\
  \Delta U &= \frac{c_V^\pu{ig}}{c_P^\pu{ig} - c_V^\pu{ig}} (RT_2 - RT_1) \\
  \Delta U &= \frac{1}{(c_P^\pu{ig}/ c_V^\pu{ig}) - 1} (RT_2 - RT_1)
  \hspace{1 cm} (\text{Use ideal gas law}) \\
  \Delta U &= \frac{1}{\gamma - 1} (P_2V_2 - P_1V_1) \tag{2} \\
\end{align}
And by the definition of enthalpy, using Eq. (2)
\begin{align}
  \Delta H &= \Delta U + \Delta (PV) \\
  \Delta H &= \frac{1}{\gamma - 1} (P_2V_2 - P_1V_1) + \Delta (PV) \\
  \Delta H &= \Delta (PV)\left(\frac{1}{\gamma - 1} + 1\right) \rightarrow
  \Delta H = \left(\frac{\gamma}{\gamma - 1}\right)\Delta (PV) \tag{3}
\end{align}
So, it was not necessary to specify how state $1$ goes from state $2$. Nevertheless, it respects Eq. (1)
\begin{align}
  \Delta H &= \left(\frac{\gamma}{\gamma - 1}\right) (P_2V_2 - P_1V_1) \\
  \Delta H &= \left(\frac{\gamma}{\gamma - 1}\right) (RT_2 - RT_1) \\
  \Delta H &= \left(\frac{R\gamma}{\gamma - 1}\right) (T_2 - T_1) = 0 \therefore T_2 = T_1 \tag{4}
\end{align}

Comment: Nice derivation. +1 // BTW the OP is not a proof, as it skips many deriving steps, taking the first equation for Delta U from thin air, with trivial following steps.

Comment: You could limit it to perfect gas = ideal gas with constant heat capacities.

Comment: @Poutnik Thanks Poutnik! Yes, those are the needed conditions to arrive to that equation.